# how to get authenticationToken to put in pass.json

Tags: ios, web-services, passbook

Now I can add pass by link from my web service. Next, I want to be able to update that pass. Thus, I need to add webserviceURL and authenticationToken, but how to get this token ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You make it up.  The only requirement is that it is at least 16 characters long.

This token is used by the device, in conjunction with the serialNumber and passTypeIdentifier to authenticate against your web service and let it know that the device is authorised to receive a particular pass.

In PHP you could do something like:

```
$authToken = generateAuthToken();

function generateAuthToken($length = 16) {
    return substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! and one more thing about webserviceURL, can I use this :   "webServiceURL" : "https://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebservice/" ? I put php file, pass.pkpass, etc in /application/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebservice/

Comment: Perhaps...  but you may face firewall issues on your Mac (try testing that you can access http://192.168.1.202:8888 from safari in an iOS device connected to the same network).  You will also have to set your test device to use http (in Settings->Developer) and make sure that your webServiceURL key contains the leading http - e.g. `"webServiceURL" : "http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebservice"`

Comment: Also, you will need to build a full web service at `/application/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebservice/` and will probably need use a database to store device IDs, device tokens and serial numbers.  Just dumping the .pkpass files in that location is not going to work.

Comment: yes, I test it in device already, it works, but I not yet register this device to my database !

Comment: on registration, your device will call `http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebservice/v1/devices/{deviceID}/registrations/{passTypeIdentifier}/{serialNumber}` where the items in { } will be unique to each pass.  Your service should also verify that the request header contains `ApplePass {authenticationToken}`.

Comment: This is authToken I get: FcAXwHyKSnVPaxOd , by your code , so I put like this: "authenticationToken":"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

Comment: You mean after add the pass, i need to use method POST to send http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebservice/v1/devices/{deviceID}/registrations/‌​{passTypeIdentifier}/{serialNumber} .

Comment: when do I generate AuthToken ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26139/discussion-between-passkit-and-smallgirl)

Comment: why error appear: [24-Apr-2013 10:10:25 Europe/Berlin] Passbook Error Log: [2013-04-24 15:08:13 +0700] Unregister task (for device c3f8344497e8f53f446c16622209eda1, pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 0001; with web service url http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/) encountered error: Authentication failure

Comment: Because you haven't implemented the Unregister method?

Comment: yes, because there's not deviceID in registration table. When register, only device is inserted, but for registration, update query doesn't work. When I test in SQL of MAMP, it works. This is my query: update registration set deviceID = '$deviceID', passTypeID ='$passTypeID', serialNo = '$serial' where deviceID = ' ' and passTypeID = ' ' and serialNo = ' '

Comment: This will never update because the criteria ` deviceID = ' ' and passTypeID = ' ' and serialNo = ' ' ` will never match any records.  Are you sure that you should't be using `insert` for this and not `update`

Comment: when I insert to user table, i insert to registration table :     mysql_query("INSERT INTO registration(deviceID,passTypeID,serialNo,userID) VALUES('','','','$newUserID')");

Comment: or I insert 'null' instead of ''?

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. Think what would happen if you added more than one user to the DB before their pass registers?  The first would match update and would update all blank records with their details, then the second would not match at all. The best place for the userID is in the Pass Table, against the serial and passid of the pass that they have registered. Then when you receive a registration request just use an insert to insert to create a new record in the device table.  You can store the user record in there as well if you like, but not before the device registers.